# Return most recent DateTime C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

```
Job -> Many Quotes 
Quote -> EmailLogList
EmailLogList -> Many EmailLogs
```

I want to return a CreatedDate from an EmailLog which has been created most recently - using a Job.Guid.

Is this the best way possible?

```
public DateTime? GetMostRecentEmailLog(Guid jobGuid)
{
    using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
        IEnumerable<Guid?> logLists = dbContext
            .Jobs
            .Include(j => j.Quotes)
            .First(j => j.Guid == jobGuid)
            .Quotes
            .Where(q => q.EmailLogListGuid != null)             
            .Select(q => q.EmailLogListGuid);

        return dbContext
            .EmailLogs
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedDate)                  
            .Where(e => logLists.Contains(e.EmailLogListGuid))
            .Select(e => e.CreatedDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();                              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This frequently used pattern...

> ```
> entities.First().Property
> ```

... is hardly ever an economical way to do querying. It fetches a complete entity from the database of which subsequently all but one property is discarded. Or, when `Property` is a lazy loaded collection, *everything* is discarded.

*In general* a better way is...

> ```
> entities.Where(e => e.Id == id).Select(e => e.Property).First()
> ```

... because this only gets the single property from the database.

Or, if `Property` is a collection,...

> ```
> entities.Where(e => e.Id == id)
>         .SelectMany(e => e.Property)
>         .Select(p => p.Property1)
> ```

Applying this would turn the first statement into...

```
IEnumerable<Guid> logLists = dbContext.Jobs
                                      .Where(j => j.Guid == jobGuid)
                                      .SelectMany(j => j.Quotes)
                                      .Where(q => q.EmailLogListGuid != null)             
                                      .Select(q => q.EmailLogListGuid.Value);
```

The second part is OK. Getting the most recent item from a collection always requires some ordering that defines "most recent".

Note that using the improved form, EF will translate this into one query, because `logList` isn't materialized yet. It is an expression tree<sup>1</sup> that can be merged with the second expression. If you want, you can create one statement in LINQ as well:

```
return dbContext.Jobs
                .Where(j => j.Guid == jobGuid)
                .SelectMany(j => j.Quotes)
                .SelectMany(q => dbContext.EmailLogs
                    .Where(e => q.EmailLogListGuid == e.EmailLogListGuid))
                .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .Select(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, if `Quote` has a navigation property `EmailLogs` (recommended):

```
return dbContext.Jobs
                .Where(j => j.Guid == jobGuid)
                .SelectMany(j => j.Quotes)
                .SelectMany(q => EmailLogs)
                .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .Select(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Even though you cast the expression tree to `IEnumerable`, it's still an `IQueryable` containing an expression.